# ReactJS how to import custom components in scrip.js file as below

Tags: reactjs

I have three files

```
 index.html
 home.js(component)
 script.js(main file).
```

===========================================

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>ReactJS Application</title>
   </head>
    <body class="bgImg">

   <script src="react/js/react-15.0.0.js"></script>
   <script src="react/js/react-dom-15.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-   core/5.8.34/browser.min.js"></script>
   <script src="react/js/react-router.js"></script>


 <!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- local script -->
<script src="local/js/components/home.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    <script src="local/js/routings/script.js" type="text/babel"></script>


<!-- bootstrap styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <!-- local styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="local/css/style.css">

<!-- appending data here -->
<div id="reactApp"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

====================================

**home.js**

```
var Home = React.createClass({

 render: function() {
      return (
              <div className="info">
                 <p>Home component</p>
            </div>
            )
   }
 });
```

**script.js**

```
 import {Home} from '../components/home.js';

 var Router = ReactRouter;

 var Link = Router.Link;

 var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;

var Route = Router.Route;

var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

/*
 * MenuComponent default component
 */

var MenuComponent = React.createClass({

render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
            <div className="header">
                <ul>
                <li><Link to="home">Home</Link></li>    
                <li><Link to="register">Register</Link></li>

                </ul>

         </div>

                <center>
                      <RouteHandler></RouteHandler>
                  </center>


        </div>
      )
    }

 });//end  menu component
```

/*Register component*/

```
 var Register = React.createClass({

   render: function() {
      return (
              <div>
                 <h5><u>Registration using React</u></h5>
                      <form>
                         <table className="registerTable">
                           <tbody>
                                 <tr><td>Enter First Name:</td><td><input     type="text" className="fname"/></td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Enter Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" className="lname"/></td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Enter Phno:</td><td><input type="text" className="phno"/></td></tr>
                                 <tr><td>Enter EmailId:</td><td><input type="text" className="email"/></td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                           <div className="buttons">
                              <input className="register btn-primary" onClick={this.register} type="button" value="Register"/><input onClick={this.register_reset} className="register_reset btn-primary" type="button" value="Reset"/>
                           </div>
                      </form>
                  </div>
            )
   }
 });



/*
* routes configuration
 */

var routes = (
    <Route name="home" path="/" handler={MenuComponent}>

        <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />

        <Route name="register" handler={Register} />


        </Route>
  );

  /*running the routes*/

 Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {

    ReactDOM.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById('reactApp'));

 });
```

=====================================

after run the above code
i am getting error in browser console as below

```
script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:5:25)
at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
at l (browser.min.js:3)
at browser.min.js:3
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ routing.js:2
 n.run @ browser.min.js:3
 l @ browser.min.js:3
  (anonymous) @ browser.min.js:3
s.onreadystatechange @ browser.min.js:3

script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:5:25)
at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
at l (browser.min.js:3)
at browser.min.js:3
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ routing.js:2
n.run @ browser.min.js:3
l @ browser.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ browser.min.js:3
s.onreadystatechange @ browser.min.js:3

script.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:5:25)
at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
at l (browser.min.js:3)
at browser.min.js:3
at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)


if i write entire home.js code in the script file itself,
 the code works for me.

 But if I seperate home component and importing in   script 
 i got above error.

could anyone help to resolve this, how to import components and its usage.
```

Comment: Do you have `import React from 'react';` and `module.exports = Home;` staements in the home.js file

Comment: Yes i have added as below                                                                                        import React from 'react';

/*home component*/
var Home = React.createClass({
    
 render: function() {
          return (
            <div className="info">
               <p>Home Component</p>
          </div>
          )
    }
});
module.exports = Home;

Comment: From index.html try and remove `<script src="local/js/components/home.js" type="text/babel"></script>` as you are already importing it in the script.js file

Comment: ok let me try Shubham

Comment: Otherwise , a better way to handle these kind of issue is to have a webpack configuration set up If you are open to it,

Comment: yaa, i will try to work on webpack,  once i got this issue without webpack configuration.

Comment: i have removed <script src="local/js/components/home.js" type="text/babel"></script> but still same errror

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at eval (eval at n.run (browser.min.js:3), <anonymous>:5:25)
    at Function.n.run (browser.min.js:3)
    at l (browser.min.js:3)
    at browser.min.js:3
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (browser.min.js:3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132278/discussion-between-vallepu-veerendra-kumar-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: could anyone help that would be great for me to move further practice on reactjs.